# Optional arguments in initializer of Python class

Tags: python

I was wondering if anyone had any good ways of quickly explaining how to efficiently and pythonically create user defined objects with optional arguments.
For instance, I want to create this object:

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self, some_other_object, i, *j, *k):
        self.some_other_object = some_other_object
        self.i = i
        # If j is specified, assume it is = i
        if(j==None):
            self.j = i
        else:
            self.j = j
        # If k is given, assume 0
        if(k==None):
            self.k = 0
        else:
            self.k = k
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This isn't valid, you can't have multiple `*` arguments. The argument prefixed with a `*` becomes a *list* of *all non-keyword arguments that come after that point*.

Comment: Thanks @Lattyware , that helps. I saw the *args and *keywordsargs, etc. and thought they may have been referring to different arguments passed.

Comment: toxotes's answer is what you want, it just has one major flaw (see my comment on it).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can set default parameters:

```
class OpticalTransition(object):
    def __init__(self, chemical, i, j=None, k=0):
        self.chemical = chemical
        self.i = i
        self.k = k
        self.j = j if j is not None else i
```

If you don't explicitly call the class with `j` and `k`, your instance will use the defaults you defined in the init parameters. So when you create an instance of this object, you can use all four parameters as normal: `OpticalTransition('sodium', 5, 100, 27)`

Or you can omit the parameters with defaults with 
`OpticalTransition('sodium', 5)`, which would be interpreted as `OpticalTransition('sodium', 5, None, 0)`

You can use some default values but not all of them as well, by referencing the name of the parameter: `OpticalTransition('sodium', 5, k=27)` uses `j`'s default but not `k`'s.

Python won't allow you to do `j=i` as a default parameter (`i` isn't an existing object that the class definition can see), so the `self.j` line handles this with an `if` statement that in effect does the same thing.

Comment: *Generally, by the way, don't bother with if x == None, just do if x.* is bad advice. Many values can evaluate to `False` - if you want to check for `None`, do `if x is None:`, not `if x:`. In this example, if `j` is `0`, it will do something unexpected. -1, until this is fixed.

Comment: You're right -- I was thinking the OP was doing that to see if it existed at all, not necessarily to see if they had the value of `None`.

Comment: Fix that and I'll flip that up to a +1, this is the best answer possible apart from that. (Edit: I made the edit myself).

Comment: Thanks @toxotes , this makes sense and looks very simple.

Comment: @Lattyware You beat me to it :)

Comment: @Lattyware Shouldn't it be 'if j is not None:'? since it is already 'None' by default?

Comment: @chase Good catch, fixed - it was actually a little more complicated a fault than that, but should be good now. I felt the ternary operator is a good choice here.

Comment: Why not do `j or i` instead of `j if j is not None else i`?

Answer (score 5):

I am too new to stackoverflow to up-vote or comment, but I approve of ronak's answer. Gareth Latty's comment about default parameters is addressed by using the [default] option of the get method.

```
dictionary.get(key[, default])
```

using **args allows for less/ more readable code when there are many optional variables to be passed. It is simply passing passing dictionary key-value pairs as parameters.