# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'config'

Tags: python, discord.py

This is my Code for Music Command
I get this error Mentioned Above
Can anyone Help Me Out ?

```
class Music(commands.Cog):
    """Bot commands to help play music."""

    def __init__(self, bot, config):
        self.bot = bot
        self.config = config[__name__.split(".")[
            -1]]  # retrieve module name, find config entry
        self.states = {}
        self.bot.add_listener(self.on_reaction_add, "on_reaction_add")
```

Comment: Which command leads to the error, how do you instantiate the class instance?

Comment: Your `Music` takes two arguments: (`bot` and `config`)... you used only one

Comment: Seems like you haven't given a value to `config` when creating the object

Comment: What Value will Config Hold @Old_Arrack

Comment: When you created the `Music` class you also take config as a parameter, you might be able to avoid the error by giving it a value.

Comment: If this is really your code and you don't know what this is for, you might want to try and remove the `config` argument from your `__init__` and remove this line: `self.config = config[__name__.split(".")[-1]]  # retrieve module name, find config entry` from your code.

Comment: Or just give the parameter a [default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535655/optional-arguments-in-initializer-of-python-class)

Comment: If u are using __init__ then self also need to call as a argument position

Answer (score 1):

This likely happened because you did something like

```
a = Music(something)
```

And forgot to enter something for `config`. To solve this you could give config some default value so something like,

```
class Music(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot, config='some default thing'):
        self.bot = bot
        self.config = config[__name__.split(".")[
            -1]]  # retrieve module name, find config entry
        self.states = {}
        self.bot.add_listener(self.on_reaction_add, "on_reaction_add")
```

Or if config is required you could put something for config on the line that you called it, So using `a = Music(something,something_else)` instead of `a = Music(something)`

Comment: TQSM.... Works IG

Comment: Upvote or marking as correct answer is appreciated. :)